# How to query cross components in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Please forgive my naivety, but I wanted to check if it is possible to query cross components in the azure function app in C#.

Here is the scenario:

1. Cosmos DB

   -contains device id and appTime where we can query for some condition

   E.g. select deviceid, appTime from c where c.content.foo=something
2. IotHub

   -contains device id with some flag

   E.g. select * from devices where
   deviceidd in(result from cosmos db) and flag=false

I was wondering if there is a way where we can merge these queries where I don't have to get the list of all device ids from cosmos even when the flag for those device ids are true in iot device twin tag.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: So basically,you want to get all of your IoT device ID from IOT hub directly in stead of cosmos db?

Comment: I want the device twin from iot with the giben deviceid(derived from cosmos) and the given flag value

Comment: Have you tried using Azure IOT hub SDK to do this? This is all the C# sample here : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/tree/master/iot-hub/Samples/device